# View not returning data from the last 5 days when not hardcoding the value in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a simplified version , but I am trying to create a view that returns data from the last 5 days (including today):

```
select distinct data_dt
from(
     select *
        from table1 t
       WHERE t.data_dt BETWEEN specified_dt - 4 and specified_dt
     )
where specified_dt = date'2019-05-01';
```

This returns only the current day's worth of data.

When I enter a hardcoded date in the WHERE Clause (as shown below), I return the correct dataset. However, when I switch the hardcoded date with a parameter that i assign a value to in the outer query (as shown in the query above), it only returns the specified date in the where clause (but not the past 4 days).

```
select distinct data_dt
  from table1 t
 WHERE t.data_dt BETWEEN date'2019-05-01'- 4 and date'2019-05-01';
```

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you need/ want a view?  If I think about wanting to pass a parameter to a view and/or create data in a view, I'd tend to expect that I'd be better served with a pipelined table function (which might be clearer as well).  Is that an option for you?

Comment: yes a pipelined table function may work too. (i don't really know what that is though , haha)

Comment: `DATE` in oracle is actually a date-time value, which means your selection window is actually `'2019-04-27 00:00:00' <= t.data_dt <= '2019-05-01 00:00:00'`.  You need to use an exclusive upper-bound - `<` - to do the query safely: `WHERE t.data_dt >= date'2019-05-01'  - 4 AND t.data_dt < date'2019-05-01' + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better served with a pipelined table function rather than a view.  Particularly if the table(s) underlying the view are relatively complex, being able to explicitly write code to incorporate parameters in the query rather than hoping that the optimizer can push the predicate where it is needed can be very beneficial from a performance standpoint.

The sample table with data before and after the window you're looking for

```
create table t (
  col1 integer,
  date_dt date 
);

insert into t values( 1, date '2019-04-01' );
insert into t values( 2, date '2019-04-10' );
insert into t values( 3, date '2019-04-20' );
insert into t values( 4, date '2019-04-27' );
insert into t values( 5, date '2019-04-28' );
insert into t values( 6, date '2019-04-29' );
insert into t values( 7, date '2019-04-30' );
insert into t values( 8, date '2019-05-01' );
insert into t values( 9, date '2019-05-02' );
```

You'll need an object type, a collection, and a table function.

```
create type t_obj as object (
  col1 integer,
  date_dt date
);
/

create type tbl_obj as table of t_obj;
/

create or replace function last_5_days( p_date_dt in date )
  return tbl_obj
  pipelined
is
begin
  for i in (select * from t where date_dt between p_date_dt - 4 and p_date_dt )
  loop
    pipe row( t_obj( i.col1, i.date_dt ) );
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/
```

Now, you can query your table function, pass in your date, and get 5 rows back (April 27 - May 1)

```
select *
  from last_5_days( date '2019-05-01' );
```

An example of running this on [liveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/i5xc9djp1l25jiapdt3z3i34a)

Comment: Thanks so much, I will go back and try this when I'm back near a computer. If it doesn't work I will just open another question. thanks again sir!

Comment: i'm guessing if i want it in a view, there's no simpler method than this i'm assuming?

Comment: @Tejash's approach should work (I believe there is a typo in the `where` clause that I added a comment for).  But it may have performance issues particularly if the table is large or there are other predicates because the optimizer may not be able to push your predicate where you want it.  A table function strikes me as simpler but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Contrary to the datatype name, `DATE` in Oracle actually contains a time component, so you have boundary condition errors.  You should be using an exclusive upper-bound for date/time/timestamp types (`<`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I'm replicating the logic that the user specified in the question.  Since the user is doing an equality comparison in the question and getting results, my expectation is that the time component in this column is always midnight and that the `between` logic does do what the user wants.

Comment: I tried testing out the function and for some reason, when i try using the function (selecting from dual), the following is returned: TBL_OBJ([T_OBJ],[T_OBJ],[T_OBJ],[T_OBJ],[T_OBJ]) . Do you know what may be going on?

Comment: @JohnWick - I'm not sure I understand what you're doing.  You'd select from the function like I showed not from `dual`.  It wouldn't make sense to use a pipelined table function in the `select` list of a query.  If you did, then your front end probably has no idea how to display the object collection that would be returned.

Comment: Yes I am selecting from dual. However, I am selecting from oracle in the oracle workspace (not trying to show data on any sort of UI, haha)

Comment: @JohnWick - Don't select a pipelined table function from dual.  Don't put a pipelined table function in the `select` list of a query.  Put it in the `from` clause.  I'm assuming "oracle workspace" means that you're using the web-based APEX environment as your front end for running queries.

Comment: No actually oracle sql developer :) . and sorry -  I didn't listen to directions (my apologies).

Comment: when i try to execute 'select *
  from last_5_days( date '2019-05-01' );' ,  i get a SQL Command not properly ended error however.

Comment: @JohnWick - If you run my example exactly as I entered it, does it work?  Assuming it does, then something in your version doesn't align with my version.  You'd probably want a separate question if you can't debug the problem.

Comment: yeah i copied and pasted what you had in your answer, but i receive that error. Am i not supposed to be using Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: @JohnWick - Here's a liveSQL example running this code showing it working. 
 https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/i5xc9djp1l25jiapdt3z3i34a  Are you getting any errors prior to the final `select`?

Comment: no, i am not getting any errors. That's odd though, maybe oracle sql developer doesn't like someting? Do you happen to have oracle sql feveloper? I copied and pasted and am getting a ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error.

Comment: (i apologize btw)

Comment: weird, i am not sure then. I appreciate your help though! Thanks a bunch ( I believe i selected your answer as best answer by the way)

Comment: @JustinCave : This worked: select *
from table(last_5_days(p_date_dt => date'2019-05-01'))  .  I'm guessing we had an older version of Oracle?

Comment: @JohnWick - What version of Oracle are you using?  `table` hasn't been required in a while

Comment: 11.1 I believe. haha

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "assign a parameter in the outer query"?  That doesn't make sense.  If you want this as a "parameter", you can use `cross join`:

```
select distinct data_dt
from table1 t cross join
     (select date '2019-05-01' as specified_dt from dual) params
where t.data_dt between specified_dt - 4 and specified_dt;
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I shouldn't have simplified the problem quite so much. What i am essentially trying to do is create a view that takes a filter (or where clause) on the data_dt. But when the users specifies the date in the where clause, i am trying to not only bring back data for not only that date, but all data 4 days prior as well. Does that make any sense? haha

Comment: Also this is a 'subquery' located in the where clause of my view . i am trying to make my view dynamic by being able to return 5 days worth of data when only one date is specified. is this possible?

Comment: `DATE` in Oracle actually includes a time component, so this perpetuates boundary errors present in the original.  Safer to use an exclusive upper-bound.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . The OP states:  "This returns only the current day's worth of data."  There doesn't seem to be a time component on `specified_dt`.

Answer (score 1):

Your view (inner query in your question) should not have any date condition. All the conditions must be in outer `WHERE` clause.

Something like following:

```
select distinct data_dt
from(
     select *
        from table1 t
       WHERE <other conditions> -- removed between condition from here
     )
where data_dt = between specified_dt - 4 and specified_dt; -- condition here
```

**-- update --**

You can use `connect by level` to generate total 5 rows from 1 row and then compare it with your date as following:

```
select distinct data_dt -- changed this, try now
from(
     select t.*, t.data_dt - days.lvl + 1 as data_dt_5days
        from table1 t
        Cross Join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 5) days
       WHERE <other_conditions>
     )
where data_dt_5days = date'2019-05-01';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: What i am essentially trying to do is create a view that takes a filter (or where clause) on the data_dt. But when the users specifies the date in the where clause, i am trying to not only bring back data for not only that date, but all data 4 days prior as well.

Comment: Also this is a 'subquery' located in the where clause of my view . i am trying to make my view dynamic by being able to return 5 days worth of data when only one date is specified. is this possible?

Comment: See the updated answer now, if it is what you are asking.

Comment: Hmm i don't think that works. i still only return that one date

Comment: I think you'd want the outer query to be `where data_dt = date'2019-05-01';` since that will be the same for all 5 days

Comment: `DATE` in Oracle actually includes a time component, so this perpetuates boundary errors present in the original. Safer to use an exclusive upper-bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really creating a view, something like this might work for you:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table_view AS
  SELECT t.data_dt+5 AS MAX_DATE, t.*
  FROM table1 t
  WHERE <OTHER_CONDITIONS>;
```

Once your view is created, you can just do a select like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_view tv
WHERE to_date('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN tv.data_dt AND tv.max_date; --Or whatever date you needed
```

Comment: darn, so there's no way to dynamically have it draw the 5 dates?

Comment: @JohnWick If you aren't really looking for a view, just take that view query and drop it into the FROM portion of the bottom query.

Comment: I am looking for a view; however, there will be many more than 5 dates in that table . (~500). What i am looking for is this:

Comment: I am looking for a view. When i specify the date (i.e. 1/5/2019), i want entries related to the last 4 days + that date (so 5 days) total. So in essence, the query would return data for 01/01/2019, 01/02/2019, 01/03/2019, 01/04/2019 and 01/05/2019. Does that make sense? haha.

Comment: Ignoring the issue that `DATE` in Oracle has a time component, and there would be boundary issues relating to that, you're using a computed column in a search condition, which can be expensive (although if there's only 500 rows, not that much of an issue).